# How to add a prefix to every element of a set in Dart?

Tags: dart

I initialize a set as

```
Set<String> ids = <String>{'1','2','3','4','5'};
```

How can I add a prefix such as ios_ to the set of ids such that the result is

```
Set<String> ids = <String>{'ios_1','ios_2','ios_3','ios_4','ios_5'};
```

Comment: use the map function

Comment: `var prefixedIds = {for (var id in ids) 'ios_$id'};`

Answer (score 1):

You can use `map()` :

```
var result = ids.map((val) => 'ios_$val').toSet();
```